# Kafka Streams: how to get offset limits prior to application for reprocessing and how to stop it

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

I'm looking for a way to do a reprocessing tool in KafkaStreams, that will allow to reprocess data from the beginning in a topic (applying some filters and writing updated versions of those events to the same topic). At the same time there is a long-running application processing data from that topic.

In order to reprocess *only up to the point in time* at which the application is launched and stops after it, it is needed to know when to stop, which is the latest produced offset at that point. E.g. a map could be constructed prior to start the topology that will have (partition -> offset) to know those limits, so the application will be able to stop when that offset is reached, comparing current partition and offset (via Processor API) with the offset limit on that initial map.

Is it possible/does it make sense to access latest offsets info from within Kafka Streams? Is there another way to work it around?
(I guess you can get it creating via regular Kafka consumers, seeking end and getting position, but I'm asking if there is an integrated solution within KafkaStreams).

Also, how to gently stop an application only when all of the partitions have reached its offset, knowing this info is distributed so you'll need to know the state from all instances?

Kafka/KafkaStreams 2.1, Scala 2.12

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using a consumer to get the end-offset seems reasonable. For stopping the application, you would need to build a manual solution that tracks the progress. For example, using `transformValues()` you could inspect the topic name, partition, and offset of an input record (using `context` object provided via `init()` method). This should allow you to call `KafkaStreams#close()` when all data is processed.

You might be interested in this KIP (in active atm) that discussed similar ideas: https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/KIP-95%3A+Incremental+Batch+Processing+for+Kafka+Streams

Comment: I think I'll have to implement sth like what the KIP proposes. Some doubts: 

   - `stop processing this partition (i.e., pause the partition)`: how to do that within KS? I know I can ignore new data, but how to "pause" ? 

  - `last running member of the group, i.e., the application will also be the group leader and will know if it is the only running instance)` , is this where `KafkaStreams.close()` should be called, right? However, in a containerised scenario where tasks will restart on failure, they should read the marker to see if they should just die on start because it finished.

Comment: In Kafka Streams you cannot `pause()` a partition (the KIP would change Kafka Streams so Kafka Streams can do this internally, but it's not exposed). Determining when to `close()` is tricky -- especially if you implement it manually. I mentioned the KIP to point out design choices -- I doubt that you can implement it 1:1 without modifying Kafka Streams itself, but you will need to make some different tradeoffs.

Comment: Is it possible instead to know whether you're at the offset end in KS? I.e. zero lag. That would help. since I'd be OK to stop when we know that we have consumed the whole partition, to make sure all content before _now_ has been reprocessed.

Comment: https://docs.confluent.io/current/streams/faq.html#accessing-record-metadata-such-as-topic-partition-and-offset-information

Comment: Sure, `ProcessorContext` gives you context about where you are, i.e. what is your offset at that point regardless of the records after it, so you could compare yours with _something_. My question was directed to whether it can know what is the latest partition offset at that moment regardless of where you are. ... so I'd have to get this beforehand like I said in question. I was wondering if instead there is a way through KS that can tell you cleanly if you are at the offset end.

Comment: Kafka Streams cannot tell you -- you will need to get the end manually beforehand.